# Balance the discharge between BAT0 and BAT1 on Thinkpad T450s running Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo, battery, thinkpad, tlp

I am using tlp on a Thinkpad T450s running Linux/Ubuntu to control the battery health, in particular setting charge thresholds etc. This works perfectly (like, startThreshold 70, stopThreshold 80 saves my battery from over charging and hysteresis).

However I have two batteries, BAT0 and BAT1, and I noticed that the way they are used is that the first battery is first fully used until empty, before the second battery gets similarly used. This sound ineffective, would be much better to discharge both batteries more or less similarly, to avoid deep discharges as much as possible. Like discharge 10% from BAT0, then 10% from BAT1, and iterating as many times as needed.

Any idea how to do that? I tried to look around but did not find any solution - may have missed something though.

As a note, it seems that the first battery to get fully discharged is always the replaceable one. I guess it makes sense, this way it will be killed first over time, but it is also the one that is easy to change...

Comment: This type of balancing is usually done at the hardware level in the unchangeable firmware in the laptop's system board.  This is usually not something you can actually *control* as to which battery discharges first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is hardcoded in Lenovo's Firmware. You can't change it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This is sad. Naively I would have believed that it would be relatively little work for lenovo to give access to an API for controlling this kind of things, but may be wrong :)